# Transform svg parent causes blur - firefox

Tags: svg, firefox, transform, blur

When I make flip-card and insert into (front and back) the same svg code after rotateY svg on back-card display blurry (when zoomed in). An example below. I would like to add that the problem only concerns the firefox browser (Microsoft Edge, Opera - they work properly). Of course i want to have sharp svg on both side card.

Any thoughts?

```js
var front = document.querySelector('.flip-card-front');
var back = document.querySelector('.flip-card-back');
var innner = document.querySelector('.flip-card-inner');


front.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  innner.classList.toggle("flip-card-cl");
});

back.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  innner.classList.toggle("flip-card-cl");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card-cl {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div>Click card to rotate</div><br>
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <p>SHARP</p>
      <svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <p>BLUR</p>
      <svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I can see it after zooming:

[front side - sharp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHeD5.png)

[back side - blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCEMM.png)

Comment: When I run your snippet on Windows 10 and zoom in the page, I don't see any blurring.  It is still sharp.  Can you add some steps to reproduce?

Comment: Just click on card, then it rotate and then zoom page again.

Comment: Click on card to rotate, then zoom ==> It's sharp for me.

Comment: in firefox browser ?

Comment: It works fine for me in FF. Please try this: use a viewBox and no width and height for the svg element: `<svg viewBox="0 0 200 208">` By doing this the svg will take all the width available i.e the width of the `.flip-card-whatever`

Comment: @Adam Yes. In FF.